# Cannot set 'Content-Type' header for GET requests

Tags: angularjs, typescript, http-headers, http-get

I'm trying to set my GET requests to have the following header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

According to the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$http), I should set the following:

> To add or overwrite these defaults, simply add or remove a property from these configuration objects. To add headers for an HTTP
>   method other than POST or PUT, simply add a new object with the
>   lowercased HTTP method name as the key, e.g.
>   `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'My-Header' : 'value' }`

However, the following line in my `app.ts` does not compile:

```
mainapp.config(($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) => {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {"Content-Type" : "application/json";
    });
```

And the error is that the type of `get` is `string|(() => string)`.

I've tried to set

```
mainapp.config(($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) => {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = "Content-Type: application/json";
});
```

But it has no effect over my GET requests.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that a curly brace is missing in the first attempt, after `"application/json"`.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to set my GET requests to have the following header:
>
> Content-Type: application/json

But this doesn't make any sense. By definition a GET request doesn't have a body, so trying to specify a content type for something that doesn't exist, hmm...

Didn't you rather mean to set the `Accept` header to `application/json`? This would have made much more sense because this way you would indicate to the remote server how do you expect the response body from your GET request to be encoded.

As far as why your code doesn't compile is concerned, you seem to have missed a closing curly brace here. You may try setting the header like this but please note that this is wrong and a terrible workaround that shouldn't be done. Normally you should fix your broken server which enforces you to have a `Content-Type` header for a GET request.

```
if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { };
}
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

Comment: It may not make any sense, but my IIS Server expects this content type. I'm getting an error without it: `Message=The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.` Accept doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: @Mugen how the hell are you sending a GET request with an entity body?

Comment: @Mugen, IIS has nothing to do with it. IIS doesn't expect any headers. It's your code that runs on top of it. Also looking at the error message: `The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header`. This seems weird because a GET request doesn't have any body by its definition. So I would rather recommend you fixing your server side code. There's not much you could do on the client here. It's normal that the client framework would cut meaningless headers from the request (like in your case a Content-Type header when using the GET verb).

Comment: Server works if I add that header in fiddler. for the compile of the code I getting:  '{ "Content-Type": string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | (() => string)'.  Type '{ "Content-Type": string; }' is not assignable to type '() => string'.

Comment: Try like this: `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov with that I'm getting `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mainApp due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'Content-Type' of undefined`

Comment: Which variable is undefined? `$httpProvider`? `$httpProvider.defaults`? `$httpProvider.defaults.headers`? `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get`? I suspect it's the last one. See my updated answer for how you could instantiate this object before trying to set properties on it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov you don't understand, `get` is not a collection, its `string|(() => string)`. This does not compile and run in any form.

Comment: OK, then just get rid of this `ng.IHttpProvider` type and treat it as normal javascript (`mainapp.config(($httpProvider) => {`). This way the TypeScript compiler won't complain. Also nowhere in my code I have treated `get` as a collection but rather as a javascript object whose `Content-Type` property is being set.